# How to remove property fields that ObjectMapper inserts into my JSON Output?

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I'm trying to create complex JSon output file with some data(HashTable collections in one big) and got some error on serializing the output. After some investigation found that need to set Visibility to these property fields and now i see strange values for HastTable in my output, that actually i don't need them. Here is some code:

```
PrintWriter out = null;

    Map<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, String> hmReqMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, String> hmResMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, String> hmGate = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, String> hmResult = new HashMap<String, String>();
    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);

    try {
        File file = new File(outputDirectory + File.separator + "aaa" + IConst.JSON_EXTENSION);

        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true)));

        if (tcStats != null) {
            for (SingleTest singleTest : tcStats.getTestsList()) {
                Map<String, String> reqMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Map<String, String> resMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                SomeClassAllDetails allDdetails = singleTest.getSiteTransaction();

                for (Entry<String, String> entry : allDetails.getEPowerEntries().entrySet()) {
                    String key = entry.getKey();
                    String value = entry.getValue();

                    if (key.startsWith("req.")) {
                        reqMap.put(key.substring(4), value);
                    } else if (key.startsWith("res.")) {
                        resMap.put(key.substring(4), value);
                    }

                }

                hmGate.put("Gate", singleTest.getGate().toString());
                hmReqMap.put("Request", reqMap.toString().substring(1, reqMap.toString().length() - 1));
                hmResMap.put("Response", resMap.toString().substring(1, resMap.toString().length() - 1));
                hmResult.put("Result", singleTest.getComparisonResult().toString());

                hm.putAll(hmGate);
                hm.putAll(hmReqMap);
                hm.putAll(hmResMap);
                hm.putAll(hmResult);

                ja.put(hm);

                mainObj.put(singleTest.getLabel(), ja);

            }

            String mapAsJson = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(mainObj);
            out.println(mapAsJson);

            out.println(",");

        } else if ("opening".equals(type)) {
            out.println("{");
        } else if ("closing".equals(type)) {
            out.println("}");
        }
```

That's the actually output and as you can see the keys like map,myArrayList are added here:

```
{
  "map" : {
    "Tran_ID" : {
      "myArrayList" : [ {
        "map" : {
          "Response" : "value1=333333 value2=33333, value4=5555",
          "Request" : "value6=44444, value7=000000",
          "Gate" : "10.0.0.1",
          "Result" : "Done"
        }
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

How do i remove them? 
If i remove the following code

```
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
```

then i got error that i need to disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS

My goal is to create this Json Output:

```
    {
   "Tran_ID" : [{
             "Response" : "value1=333333 value2=33333, value4=5555",
              "Request" : "value6=44444, value7=000000",
              "Gate" : "10.0.0.1",
              "Result" : "Done"
     }]
 }
```

Comment: Changed and added what i need to get..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is a solution:

1. Go to http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ (NB: I'm not affiliated with this site, it's just a handy tool)
2. Select "Source type": "JSON" and you correct jackson version below. Also uncheck "Allow additional properties" (on the the right)
3. Copy/paste your wanted JSON on the left big text box.
4. Clic on preview at the bottom, this will generates your java classes.
5. Next step is to "fill" a class instance with your data

Sample "filling" code (with generated classes name):

```
TranID tranId = new TranID(); // {}
tranId.setResponse("value1=333333, value2=33333, value4=5555"); // { "Response": ... }
tranId.setRequest("value6=44444, value7=000000"); // { "Response": ..., "Request": ... }
tranId.setGate("10.0.0.1"); // etc
tranId.setResult("Done")
Example example = new Example(); // { "tranID": undefined }
example.setTranId(new ArrayList<>()); // { "tranID": [] }
example.getTranId().add(tranId); // { "tranID": [{ "Response": ..., "Request": ... }] }
// output
String json =  mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(example);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, but it didn't really help to problem
and I rewrote the code and put this one:

```
    String jo = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                        .add(singleTest.getLabel(), Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                .add("Request", reqMap.toString().substring(1, reqMap.toString().length() - 1))
                                .add("Response", resMap.toString().substring(1, resMap.toString().length() - 1))
                                .add("Result", singleTest.getComparisonResult().toString())
                                .add("Gate", singleTest.getGate().toString()))
                        .build().toString();
```

You should also add to pom.xml these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
<version>1.0.4</version>
```

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.json</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
```

And then you can do whatever you want with you string.

Thanks